# NodeJS Example - Firebase Cloud Functions - Instantiate an Admin SDK Directory service object

Tags: node.js, jwt, google-cloud-functions, google-admin-sdk, service-accounts

### Goal

Use `googleapis` with Firebase Cloud Functions to get a list of all users in my G Suite domain.

### Question

How do I [Instantiate an Admin SDK Directory service object](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation#instantiate_an_admin_sdk_directory_service_object). I do not see a NodeJS example, and I'm not clear how to setup and make the request with `googleapis`.

### Context

This code runs from Firebase Cloud Functions, and it seems to authenticate okay. Now, how do I setup the service object at `//TODO` in the following code:

```
// Firebase Admin SDK
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase)

// Google APIs
const googleapis = require('googleapis')
const drive = googleapis.drive('v3')
const gsuiteAdmin = googleapis.admin('directory_v1')

// Service Account Key - JSON
let privatekey = require("./privatekey.json")

let jwtClient = new googleapis.auth.JWT(
    privatekey.client_email,
    null,
    privatekey.private_key,
    ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user'])

// Firebase Cloud Functions - REST
exports.authorize = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    //authenticate request
    jwtClient.authorize(function (err, tokens) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
            return
        } else {
            console.log("Successfully connected!")
        }

        // TODO
        // USE SERVICE OBJECT HERE??
        // WHAT DOES IT LOOK LIKE?

        response.send("Successfully connected!")
    })
})
```

Comment: My first JWT wasn't providing Domain-Wide Delegation, and when I added an **impersonator** I got errors.  The code and setup is fine. I created a **new** key in my Service Account (which was already set up with DwD), and I swapped in the new key.json (auto downloaded from GCP). This solved the issue, and the App is making requests to the drive api as any user in our G Suite Domain! When I get code for using the Directory API, I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Order of Operations:

1. Create Service Account Credentials in Google Cloud Console
2. Add Domain-Wide Delegation to the Service Account
3. Authorize the API in G Suite - Security - Advanced
4. Go back to the Service Account and Download the `.json` key file

I downloaded the `.json` key file too soon, e.g., before authorizing the APIs in G Suite. The order, Setting up the Service Account with DwD and **then** authorization the API in G Suite API and **then** downloading the `.json` key file is important.

### The Example

```
// Firebase Admin SDK
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase)

// Google APIs
const googleapis = require('googleapis')
const drive = googleapis.drive('v3')
const directory = googleapis.admin('directory_v1')

// Service Account Key - JSON
let privatekey = require("./privatekey.json")
let impersonator = 'example@example.com'

let jwtClient = new googleapis.auth.JWT(
    privatekey.client_email,
    null, // not using path option
    privatekey.private_key,
    ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly'],
    impersonator
)

// Firebase Cloud Functions - REST
exports.getUsers = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    //authenticate request
    jwtClient.authorize(function (err, tokens) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
            return
        } else {
            console.log("Successfully connected!")
        }
        //Google Drive API
        directory.users.list ({
            auth: jwtClient,
            domain: 'example.com',
            maxResults: 10,
            orderBy: 'email',
            viewType: 'domain_public'
          }, function(err, res) {
            if (err) {
              console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err)
              return;
            }
            var users = res.users;
            if (users.length == 0) {
              console.log('No users in the domain.');
            } else {
              console.log('Users:');
              for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
                var user = users[i];
                console.log('%s (%s)', user.primaryEmail, user.name.fullName)
              }
              response.send(users)
            }        
        })
    })
})
```

### UPDATE

The *example* above is not secure. A Cloud Function, especially with G Suite Domain-wide Delegation, should not respond to http requests unless they come from your application. See [in this example](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/authorized-https-endpoint/functions) that the Cloud Function uses `admin.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken)...` to validate that the request is authenticated by Firebase.

If you don't properly handle your G Suite DwD Cloud Function, **you risk exposing your G Suite API to the public.**